# JavaFX: How can I use correctly a ProgressIndicator in JavaFX

Tags: java, thread-safety, task, javafx-8

I´m newbe in JavaFX.
I have a problem with my JavaFX application, I need to start my ProgressIndicator (type INDETERMINATE) before a database query.
This is part of my code:

```
spinner.setVisible(true);
passCripto = cripto.criptoPass(pass);
MyDao dao = new MyDaoImpl();
boolean isLoginOk = dao.isUserOk(user, passCripto);
boolean isStatusOk = dao.idStatusUser(user);
```

When finished, I need to set spinner to FALSE but the spinner only is showed when database query is finished. How can I solve this ?

Thanks.

I do this, but not resolved:

```
Task<Boolean> taskValidaLogin = new Task<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
        boolean validaLogin = ACDCDao.validaUsuario(usuario, senhaCripto);

        return validaLogin;
    }
};

Task<Boolean> taskValidaStatus = new Task<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
        boolean validaStatus = ACDCDao.validaStatusUsuario(usuario);

        return validaStatus;
    }
};

new Thread(taskValidaLogin).start();
new Thread(taskValidaStatus).start();
if (taskValidaLogin.getValue()) {
    if (taskValidaStatus.getValue()) {
        //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to do your database stuff into an other thread, cause if the operation take time it will freez the JavaFX thread (The GUI)

In JavaFx you can use Service and Task to do background stuff. You should read

- [Concurency in javafx](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)
- [Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html)

By executing your database stuff into a service, you will be able to monitor it easely cause Service provide the necessary to do that, and have method like onSuccedeed, onFailed...

Really have a look to that, is an essential part if you want to do JavaFx correctly.

### Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

### ServiceExample.java

```
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class ServiceExample extends Service<String> {
    @Override
    protected Task<String> createTask() {
        return new Task<String>() {
            @Override
            protected String call() throws Exception {
                //DO YOU HARD STUFF HERE
                String res = "toto";
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                return res;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

### Controller.java

```
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ProgressIndicator progressIndicator;

    public void initialize() {
        final ServiceExample serviceExample = new ServiceExample();

        //Here you tell your progress indicator is visible only when the service is runing
        progressIndicator.visibleProperty().bind(serviceExample.runningProperty());
        serviceExample.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent workerStateEvent) {
                String result = serviceExample.getValue();   //here you get the return value of your service
            }
        });

        serviceExample.setOnFailed(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent workerStateEvent) {
                //DO stuff on failed
            }
        });
        serviceExample.restart(); //here you start your service
    }
}
```

### sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="Controller">
    <ProgressIndicator fx:id="progressIndicator" layoutX="78.0" layoutY="55.0"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

I do that example quickly it's basic but I think it's what you want. (I don't add my progressIndicator to a node it's just for the example)

Comment: agoninst_, you are correct. I have idea for this but I don´t now how I´ll do. Do you have an example ? Thank you.

Comment: I´m lost in this example. I´m newbee. Where I put my code ?

Answer (score 5):

After `spinner.setVisible(true);`, start the spinner spinning by setting it to an indeterminate value (-1).  `spinner.setProgress(-1d);`

Then I guess when the task is done you want it stopped.  There are two events to use, succeeded and failed.  That means the task failed, not the login.  Here's an example for succeeded.

```
taskValidaStatus.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
        spinner.setProgress(0d);
        //and now you can check valida here after the task is finished
        if (taskValidaLogin.getValue()) {
            if (taskValidaStatus.getValue()) {
            //do something
            }
    }
});
//now start the tasks after they're all set up.
new Thread(taskValidaLogin).start();
new Thread(taskValidaStatus).start();
```

I didn't test this code because you didn't provide a working example.

There's another issue in that validaLogin may not be finished yet.  I only checked if one thread was finished.  What you should do is start one thread in the other threads onSucceeded event.  I'm not sure of the order you need, but it might look like this in the taskLogin onSucceeded.

```
        if (taskValidaLogin.getValue()) {
            new Thread(taskValidaStatus).start();
        }
```